# PostgreSQL: Effective group by any column with timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have one big table (about 1 million records) with 50 columns (one timestamp and other entity's parameters) and I want to make queries like:

```
select param_name, count(*) 
from big_table 
where timestamp > {{start}} and timestamp < {{end}} 
group by param_name
```

So how I can make execution of this queries as fast as possible? Time bounds can be arbitrary. I am using PostgreSQL.

Now I am thinking about making 50 INDEXes kind of (timestamp, param_name). But it can provide huge indexes.

Is there any better solution?

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A million records with 50 columns is not particularly large.

I would start with the obvious index on `big_table(timestamp, param_name)` and see how that works.

Actually, the index on `big_table(time_stamp)` would be sufficient under many circumstances -- particularly, if you are only trying to summarize a small minority of rows.